# Downloading File Using Telnet

Tags: linux, download, telnet

I'm trying to download a file,  https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/putty.exe or https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1806-x64.exe, without using `curl` or `wget`; rather, I want to download the file by using `telnet` as follows.

```
(echo 'GET /~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/putty.exe'; echo ""; sleep 1; ) | telnet the.earth.li 80 > s.exe
```

This does not work;  when I use `cat` the file contents are as follows.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 18:40:22 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/w64/putty.exe
Content-Length: 301
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/w64/putty.exe">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at the.earth.li Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: In the reply from the server, you see that the document has moved to a new address.  It also tells you what the new address is.

Comment: after following the new address, you’ll also have to remove the http header from the response

Comment: You are going to have to be very good at hand-writing TLS handshakes to do that with telnet from an HTTPS URL. I think you're out of luck.

Comment: forget what I said, the command "(echo 'GET /~sgtatham/putty/0.70/w64/putty.exe'; echo ""; sleep 1; ) | telnet the.earth.li 80 > s.exe " seems to just work without even having to remove headers

Comment: If you have openssl installed, `openssl s_client -host the.earth.li -port 443 -crlf` will do the job. Otherwise you may want to put a copy somewhere HTTP-accessible.

Comment: The server is http-accessible though, I just tried. The redirect was just for the 0.70 in the address

Answer (score 1):

From the reply you can see that the "document has moved" to "https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/w64/putty.exe", so you should just change the link in your command (change "latest" to "0.70"). 
Your browser does this automatically. The command should be: 
`(echo 'GET /~sgtatham/putty/0.70/w64/putty.exe'; echo ""; sleep 1; ) | telnet the.earth.li 80 > s.exe`